# Cannot read pdf generated by iText __OKBPDF

Tags: java, android, itext

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;

import com.itextpdf.text.Document;
import com.itextpdf.text.Paragraph;

    import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfWriter;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private static String FILE = "/HelloWorld.pdf";
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
</i>

        try {
            Document document = new Document();
            boolean mExternalStorageAvailable = true;
            boolean mExternalStorageWriteable = false;
            String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();

            if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state)) {
            // We can read and write the media
            mExternalStorageAvailable = mExternalStorageWriteable = true;
            } else if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED_READ_ONLY.equals(state)) {
            // We can only read the media
            mExternalStorageAvailable = true;
            mExternalStorageWriteable = false;
            } else {
            // Something else is wrong. It may be one of many other states, but all we need
            //  to know is we can neither read nor write
            mExternalStorageAvailable = mExternalStorageWriteable = false;
            }
            String file = null;
            if(mExternalStorageWriteable) {
            file = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + FILE;
            }

            PdfWriter.getInstance(document,new FileOutputStream(file));
            document.open();
            Paragraph p = new Paragraph("Hello iText World!");
            document.add(p);
            document.close();

            } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            }
    }


}
```

I'm trying to generate one more for another set of data and generated file has size 0kb, and whene opened shows message "Adobe Reader could not open "List.pdf"  and type or beacuse the file has been damaged".

Comment: Are you sure you're not missing any exception logged in the logcat? On first glance, this code seems to be correct.

Answer (score 0):

iText needs a License key. Check you logcat for the exception. Go onto their site to get a license key and to see how to implement it.